# Does IAP completes when download fails in IAP Hosted Content?

Tags: ios6, in-app-purchase, iap-hosted-content

I am using the new hosted content option in iOS6.

My question is - Does Apple charge the user even if the download fails ?

Or in other words do I need to let the user repurchase the product or just download it again ?

Thanks
Shani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the user is charged for the purchase and afterwards, he can download your hosted content.